# no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body select[name='Accept']"}

Tags: php, automated-tests

I have this

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('user.invite_accept',[$user->id,1])}}">Accept</a></li>
```

I am trying to click on it using laravel dusk I used select, click,clicklink 
 But it doesn't work

Comment: `body select[name='Accept']` would select a `select` element somewhere inside body, that has the name `Accept`. What that is supposed to have even remotely to do with the HTML code you have shown … no idea.

Comment: The phrase "it doesn't work" doesn't convey what is happening, other than to say that whatever is going on doesn't match your unstated expectations. Let us know what you expect to happen, and be more specific about what is happening that you don't want to happen. Does anything happen, are there error messages in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector seems to be wrong, it appears that you're trying to click a [hyperlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) which is represented by [`<a>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) while your CSS expression is looking for a [`<select>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Try converting your locator to [find element by link text](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/how-to-locate-element-by-link-text-and-partial-link-text-locator/) like:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Accept"))
```

or alternatively use the [XPath Locator](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727) like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Accept']"))
```

Comment: I tried this " $browser2->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::linkText('Accept'))->click();
" but I got this error "Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Accept"}"

Comment: I have many links in the page so its take the first one which the text of it is not "Accept"