# How to correct "No such element"?

Tags: php, laravel-5, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

I have this

```
<li>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('user.invite_accept',[$user->id,1])}}">
     Accept
  </a>
</li>
```

I tried this

```
 $browser2->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::linkText('Accept'))->click();
```

but I got this error

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element:
>   Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Accept"}

I have many links on the page but it takes the first one which doesn't have  "Accept" in the text

Comment: This works for me. Are you on the right page? What does the screenshot show?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body select\[name='Accept'\]"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276682/no-such-element-unable-to-locate-element-methodcss-selector-selector)