# no such element: Unable to locate element modal

Tags: php, laravel, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

I have to test this modal box and I have to 
type the name of project

```
<div class="modal fade bs-create-project-modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="create-project" style="display: block; padding-right: 14px;">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title mt-0">Create project</h5>                                              
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter project name">
                        </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">Create project</button>
```

I tried this

`->type('div.modal .fade .bs-create-project-modal input[name^=title]', 'any'`)
but got "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body select\[name='Accept'\]"}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276682/no-such-element-unable-to-locate-element-methodcss-selector-selector)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `waitFor()` to check if the modal is present.

```
$dusk->waitFor('input[name^="title"]')
    ->type('input[name^="title"]', 'any')
    ->press('Submit');
```

Comment: I tried this ....                 ->waitFor('input[name^=title]')
                    ->type('input[name^=title]', 'any') I got this error Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnrecognizedExceptionException: element not interactable @senty

Comment: I added an edit. Can you try `'input[name^="title"]'` instead. If it doesn't work, you should use `$dusk->script()` and put in jquery style. It's not the nicest way but it would work.

Comment: instead of what ?

Comment: @flower instead of `input[name^=title]` - use `"title"` in double quotes